# Restore all nugets and their dependencies to a flat folder

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have a c# project, I need to be able to restore all its nugets (and all their dependencies) to a folder and then load dynamically (using reflection) one DLL.

This single DLL might depend on other dlls that I restored (from the nugets) so I prefer having everything in the same folder.

When I run dotnet restore I get all the nugets but each package in its own folder.

I don't want to build the project, just restore.

I want to get all the dlls dropped into a single folder and also I want a specific target framework, say .net5. So if the package supports more than one, I don't want the rest.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!
Gilad